# Javascript document.getSelection() not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, browser

I've been building a javascript app for iOS devices which needs to be able to get the word directly underneath a tap event so it can be defined.
Using the following js code;

```
var s = e.browserEvent.currentTarget.getSelection();
s.modify('extend','backward','word');        
var b = s.toString();           
s.modify('extend','forward','word');
var a = s.toString();
s.modify('move','forward','character');
alert(b + a);
```

and it works in browsers (chrome and safari), but when running on devices such as an ipad, getSelection doesn't return anything.
Anybody have an idea of how to get that working?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Mobile Safari definitely supports `window.getSelection()` and I think aliases it as `document.getSelection()`. Are you sure `e.browserEvent.currentTarget` is the document?

Comment: I've tried both window and document.getSelection(), and both still return null. I've tested using alerts to see what object the device thinks the currentTarget variable is, and it appears to be the document. So despite a single click working on desktop browsers, it looks like you might actually have to have text selected for that to work. Though I hope that's not the case because it defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

For those who find this question in the future. Make sure the element you are trying to call getSelection() on has the following in it's css:

```
user-select: text;
-webkit-user-select: text;
```

This issue occurs frequently with content-editable elements.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on iOS 12 only (it was working fine on iOS 11, 10, 9)

I found a clean solution :
Look at this : https://github.com/megahertz/jquery.get-word-by-event

it uses the click EVENT object (cleaner than *window.getSelection* I think):

```
var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
```

And it works great on iOS 12.